# How make js work on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var cutTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacutbtn');
    cutTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  
    var cutTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-cuttextarea');  
    cutTextarea.select();

  try {  
    var successful = document.execCommand('cut');  
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';  
    console.log('Cutting text command was ' + msg);  
  } catch(err) {  
    console.log('Oops, unable to cut');  
  }  
});
</script>
```

So, this works perfectly on IE and chrome, but how could I make it to work in firefox? I need serious help, I don't know how to convert js to jQuery.. or if you have resolutions to my code, feel free to post. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The [cut/copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_Compatibility) is supported only from FF41

Comment: But mine is 39.0, and its freshly installed. I also wanna ask if I changed it to copy instead of cut, would it work?

Comment: so `cut/copy` is not supported..... I don't think you can use `cut/copy` for now in FF....

Comment: For now in FF, I think you will have to use the [clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Using_the_clipboard)